# WordPress homepage not loading, all other pages loading

Tags: wordpress

I've made a small website using WordPress. I've been facing a problem since quite long - my homepage is either extremely slow to load, or doesn't load at all. But all other pages of my website load at a decent speed. I tried contacting my hosting services provider (GoDaddy), but they replied that the home page resolves correctly without any errors on their side.

I tried disabling plugins too, but no help. I don't know where else to look, I'm not much of a pro.

Can anyone help me around with this problem?

Thanks.

My website: [DoubleRoot](http://doubleroot.in)

Comment: GoDaddy are wrong. It's not loading, however the server the site is on is up. 
Try replacing your index.php with an older copy as I can access other areas of your site.

e.g

http://doubleroot.in/wp-login.php?

Answer (score 2):

I guess something is wrong with your **index.php theme file**.

Change the theme to the default twenty thirteen and see if the index is loading. If it loads then definitely there is some error in your theme's index.php file.

To solve this error you will need to reupload the index.php file of your theme. **Note** that your edits made to the index.php will be overwritten so make a backup of the file first.

Comment: Essentially a copy of what I said.